How to enable squiggly lines on IntelliJ IDE on checkstyle errors?
I have add checkStyle.xml and CheckStyle-IDEA plugin, which are working fine on triggering.
However It will be better to see a squiggly line inside editor itself with errors to fix it
Do anyone knows how to enable it ?
I have tried add CheckStyle-IDEA but it is not showing errors inside editor, need a plugin or settings in IntelliJ to show errors
